# Если выбрано значение - показывать доп. поля js

Tags: javascript, php, html

Всем привет.
Есть код в php:

```
<table class="Little" cellspacing='0'>
    <div class="Little">Верификация клиента</div>


    <tr>
        <td id="ss2"><h3> Шаг 1 </h3><br>Справочная</br></td>
        <td id="dd2"><select required id='sel1' name="sel1" size = “1”>
                <option id=sel001 name="sel001" value="<?php echo $VerifSel1 ?>"><?php echo $VerifSel1 ?>(Выбрано)</option>
                    <option id=sel002 name="sel002" value="Номер отсутствует">Номер отсутствует</option>
                <option id=sel3 value="Номер предоставлен">Номер предоставлен</option>
            </select>
        <select  id="sel5" name="sel5" size = “1”>
                <option id="sel003" value="<?php echo $VerifSel2 ?>"><php echo $VerifSel2 ?>(Выбрано)"</option>
                <option value="Не соответствует">Не соответствует</option>
                <option value=”Соответствует”>Соответствует</option>
            </select></td>
        <td id="ff2"><textarea id="textarea1" name="textarea1"></textarea></td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

И к нему js:

```
$(function() {
    $("#sel1").change(function() {
        if ($("#sel3").is(":selected")) {
            $("#textarea1").show();
            $("#sel5").show();
        }else {
            $("#textarea1").hide();
            $("#sel5").hide();
        }
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

Необходимо сделать таким образом в функции, чтобы, если выбран sel001 и оно содержит значение "Номер предоставлен" - показывать селект sel5 и textarea1, с сохраненными в них данными(в php сохраняется и отправляется по AI) в противном случае из скрывать.
Подскажите, как правильно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Что-то типо этого?

```js
$('#sel1').bind('change', function(){
  let thisValue = $(this).val();
  if(thisValue=='Номер предоставлен') 
  $('#sel5').show(); else
  $('#sel5').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="sel1" name="sel1" size="1" required>
  <option id="sel001" name="sel001" value="<?php echo $VerifSel1 ?>"><?php echo $VerifSel1 ?>(Выбрано)</option>
  <option id="sel002" name="sel002" value="Номер отсутствует">Номер отсутствует</option>
  <option id="sel3" value="Номер предоставлен">Номер предоставлен</option>
</select>
<select id="sel5" name="sel5" size="1" style="display: none;">
  <option id="sel003" value="<?php echo $VerifSel2 ?>">
    <php echo $VerifSel2 ?>(Выбрано)</option>
  <option value="Не соответствует">Не соответствует</option>
  <option value=”Соответствует”>Соответствует</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Спасибо за Вашу идею, но это не совсем подходит.
У меня возникли сложности с этой функцией. По сути, поле <option id="sel001" name="sel001" value="<?php echo $VerifSel1 ?>"> вставляет значения выбранного поля sel002 или sel3, смотря что выбрано.
Это значение у меня сохраняется в php.
Мне необходимо, чтобы если выбрано поле sel3 или поле sel001 содержит значение поля sel3, то показывать sel5 и textare, но что-то при у меня в данном выражении, что Вы прислали при сохранении в значении "Номер отсутствует" всё равно появляется селект.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант c реализованной тестовой обработкой запросов(и сохранение данных в сессии) на стороне сервера и упрощенной html-разметкой:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") {
    $a = empty($_POST['a']) || !in_array($_POST['a'], ['commit', 'reset'])? 'reset': $_POST['a'];
    if ($a === 'reset') {
        $_SESSION['stash'] = [];
    } else {
        $_SESSION['stash'] = [
            'sel' => [
                1 => (int)isset($_POST['sel'][1])? $_POST['sel'][1]: 0,
                5 => (int)isset($_POST['sel'][5])? $_POST['sel'][5]: 0,
            ],
            'txt' => isset($_POST['txt'])? $_POST['txt']: ''
        ];
    }
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
} else {
    $d = isset($_SESSION['stash'])? $_SESSION['stash']: [];
    $d['sel'][1] = isset($d['sel'][1])? $d['sel'][1]: 0;
    $d['sel'][5] = isset($d['sel'][5])? $d['sel'][5]: 0;
    $d['txt'] = isset($d['txt'])? $d['txt']: "";
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>foobar</title>
<style>
.-foo .-sup {
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
    <table class="-foo">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="sel1" required name="sel[1]">
                    <option value="0"<?=$d['sel'][1] === "0"? " selected": ""?>>Номер отсутствует</option>
                    <option value="1"<?=$d['sel'][1] === "1"? " selected": ""?>>Номер предоставлен</option>
                </select>
                <select class="-sup" name="sel[5]">
                    <option value="0"<?=$d['sel'][5] === "0"? " selected": ""?>>Не соответствует</option>
                    <option value="1"<?=$d['sel'][5] === "1"? " selected": ""?>>Соответствует</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea class="-sup" name="txt"><?=htmlentities($d['txt'])?></textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="submit" name="a" value="commit">Применить</button>
                <button type="submit" name="a" value="reset">Сбросить</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
     $(function() {
        $("#sel1")
        .change(function (e) {
            var sup = $(".-foo .-sup");
            if ($(this).find(":selected").val() === "1") {
                sup.show();
            } else {
                sup.hide();
            }
        })
        .trigger('change');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
```